# sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer returns the same values for different inputs. How can I deal with it?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, floating-point

There is a fitted `pt = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson', standardize=False) (lambda = -3.2028635015981934)`. I apply it to new data and see consecutive identical values corresponding to different inputs.

```
Input:
for input_value, transformed_value in zip(bad_array, bad_array_transformed):
    print('input_value =', input_value[0])
    print('transformed_value =', transformed_value[0])
    print('---------------------')

Output:
input_value = 1577.3424035935093
transformed_value = 0.31222061116370275
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3430161583228
transformed_value = 0.3122206111637028
---------------------
input_value = 1577.343628717164
transformed_value = 0.3122206111637028
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3442412822144
transformed_value = 0.3122206111637028
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3448538412915
transformed_value = 0.31222061116370287
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3454664004878
transformed_value = 0.31222061116370287
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3460789675948
transformed_value = 0.31222061116370287
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3466915270276
transformed_value = 0.31222061116370287
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3473040926692
transformed_value = 0.3122206111637029
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3479166523382
transformed_value = 0.312220611163703
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3485292121259
transformed_value = 0.312220611163703
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3491417781227
transformed_value = 0.312220611163703
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3497543381466
transformed_value = 0.31222061116370303
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3503669043796
transformed_value = 0.31222061116370303
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3509794646407
transformed_value = 0.3122206111637031
---------------------
input_value = 1577.3515920250193
transformed_value = 0.3122206111637031
---------------------
input_value = 1577.352204591608
transformed_value = 0.3122206111637031
---------------------
input_value = 1577.352817152223
transformed_value = 0.31222061116370314
---------------------
input_value = 1577.353429719048
transformed_value = 0.31222061116370314
---------------------
```

Attempts to calculate manually using the formula give a similar result. Using the `math` library did not help too.

```
res = (np.power(((x)+1), lambda) - 1) / lambda
```

Are there any ways to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the function you're evaluating is really small. Here's the [derivative of your function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative+%28%28%28x%2B1%29**m%29+-+1%29+%2F+m%2C+m+%3D+-3.2028635015981934):

```
1/(1 + x)^4.2028635015981934
```

Evaluating this at x=1577, you get about 10^-14. So if you changed x by 1, you'd change the output by 10^-14. Since you're changing it by more like 10^-3, the change in output is roughly 10^-17. Double precision floating point  numbers only have 15 to 16 digits of precision.

> Are there any ways to deal with this problem?

You could use a different formula. This question doesn't describe *why* you're using this transformation, so I don't know what to recommend.

Comment: I am solving the task of minimizing cost without declining quality, with the help of ML to estimate quality. Now I have data with a slight change in a certain direction, but the ML model produces fluctuating values of the target variable. I started to look for the cause and found that after applying the data preparation pipeline (generating polynomial features and Yeo-Johnson transformation), a linearly changing feature turns into a staircase shape after the PT. You can find pictures here (https://dropmefiles.com/NN8xM)